# Using <script> tag AJAX method in GAS

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script, stripe-payments, google-sites

I am trying to implement a Stripe payment solution on my Google Site using Google Apps Script (“GAS”) and Stripe.com.

Stripe makes the following code available for testing.

> ```
> <div>
>     <form action="/charge" method="POST">
>         <script
>             src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
>             class="stripe-button"
>             data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
>             data-image="/square-image.png"
>             data-name="Demo Site"
>             data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
>             data-amount="2000">
>         </script>
>     </form>
> </div>
> ```

The code works [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4k8exqh/) but fails in my GAS index.html file.

Note that when I look inside my Console page in my Chrome developer tools, I see the following error message:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'StripeCheckout' of undefined
> ```

What’s going wrong? And what’s the solution?

Comment: Check your network tab for a 404 (or other errors in your console?). The Stripe API is trying to load something like: 'https://a.stripecdn.com/checkout/v3/checkout/inner-8Gvr10BOM2syy1y6NsftiQ.js' which is likely blocked by your Google Site. (thx for including the fiddle!)

Comment: I didn't see anything matching what you describe. However, when I examine the .js source file, I see the pattern "this.StripeCheckout" occurs 12 times. Now, this is where things get muddy for me so I could be off base... But in this case, I think the keyword “this” references the browser window? Also, I believe GAS does not have direct access to the DOM because of the CAJA sanitation? I think the sum effect is... “this” is undefined by the browser. And that explains the error message. Is there a solution or a workaround? I think I could do a (Google-hosted) <iframe> but that gets messy.